# How can I import all records from an Airtable table using an Azure Synapse Analytics pipeline rather than just retrieving the first 100?

Tags: pagination, analytics, azure-synapse, airtable

When using the REST integration in an Azure Synapse pipeline and supplying the proper authorization (api_key), I'm only getting 100 records loaded into my Azure Synapse data sink.  How do I ensure all records are imported?

Comment: The pagination options even though you dont defy any rules, will automatically default to RFC5988 from what I could recall, go to pagination rules and set that rule to false might solve your problem

Comment: Phung, I'm not sure what you mean by "set that rule to false" as there don't seem to be any references to RFC5988 in the Synapse REST configuration.  Could you elaborate and / or submit an answer with screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

There is a pagination offset that appears in the JSON response of Airtable.  On the Source tab of the copy data step in Synapse, under Pagination rules, select QueryParameter, enter "offset" (no quotes) into the field next to QueryParameter, and enter "$['offset']" (no quotes) into the Value.  That's it - no need for relative URL or a parameter configuration.  The pagination rule tells synapse to look for the data element "offset" in the response and to continue fetching more data until a response no longer contains that data element in the JSON. See screenshot below.  The second screenshot shows the authorization configuration.

[image]

The authorization configuration for the Airtable API is shown below - this causes Synapse to include the HTTP header and value "Authorization: Bearer " to the Airtable API. Just replace <api_key> with your Airtable api key which can be found and / or created under your account settings in Airtable.

[image]